# Proc Report - Rows of two tables

Tags: sas, proc-report

I have to export some data in the format of two tables per row, with multiple rows. So far I have got as far as building a report with multiple tables stacked on top of each other, but with only one per row by using multiple `proc report` statements in a code statement as so:

```
proc report data = mydata; title 'My Title:'; run;
proc report data = mydata; title 'My Title:'; run;
proc report data = mydata; title 'My Title:'; run;
```

What do I need to add/amend so that I get two tables per row in my report?

Thanks

Comment: You want an entirely separate table for every row, and in order (so r1t1 r1t2 r2t1 r2t2)?  That's very strange... or do you want two tables, total, with all rows falling into both tables?  What else is going on in these tables?

Comment: Hi , Joe. To clarify, on each page of my report will be two tables, side by side, with the same columns and rows, but containing different data. The report will have multiple pages. When I have run a load of proc report statements as per my example in a single code node, I get multiple pages in my report, but only one table per page. Does that make more sense?

Comment: im currently trying ods rtf file = '' but I am having trouble getting it to write out to a local windows file....it keeps thinking the root is the SAS config file location on the install i am working on.

Comment: Oh.  So you're not talking *data row*, you mean you want a 2x2 layout or something on your page.

Comment: yes. apologies for my poor, friday afternoon explanation.

Comment: No problem, probably my friday morning brain misinterpreting...

Comment: What's the ODS destination this is going to?   PDF? HTML? Multiple?

Comment: the output ultimately needs reading into an Excel file for the client. so far I am using HTML.

Comment: SAS 9.4? Or earlier?  Can you use `ODS EXCEL`?  Or does this need to go to HTML and you then want to read it in excel-side.

Comment: install is v9.4 and i am using EG...

Comment: `proc product_status; run;` This will give you the exact SAS version and it matters here. ODS EXCEL is not production until SAS 9.4 TS1M3.

Comment: @Reeza Doesn't matter much anyway does it, `ODS EXCEL` doesn't support this (which is very unfortunate as this is a common use case in excel sadly).

Comment: @gdogg371 Also - your second comment about ods rtf, you're not going to be able to write locally from EG if you're using it in server mode unless your desktop is shared somehow; not sure if that's what you're saying you're doing, but...

Answer (score 2):

Some destinations support this directly in the `ODS` statement; like `ODS PDF`.

```
ods pdf file="test.pdf" columns=2  ;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;

proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables age;
run;
ods pdf close;
```

However, HTML doesn't.  For those you'll want to use `ODS LAYOUT`.

```
ods html file="test.html";
ods layout gridded 
        columns=2;
ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods region;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables age;
run;
ods layout end;
ods html close;
```

See the [ODS Layout Tip Sheet](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/Tipsheet_ods_layout.pdf) for more details.

ODS LAYOUT won't work with ODS EXCEL, sadly. You can use [this macro](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/A_Poor/Rich_SAS_Users_Proc_Export) to do something similar, if you prefer, or perhaps use `PROC DOCUMENT` to get the tables together, but I'm not sure exactly how that would work.

If you want more than one table in each column, then you can either have one `ODS REGION` per table (they'll end up being alternated l-r-l-r) or you can just add more to the two `ODS REGION`s here if you don't need them to be gridded properly.

IE:

```
ods html file="test.html";
ods layout gridded 
        columns=2;
ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods region;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables age;
run;
ods layout end;
ods html close;
```

Those just have two columns with 2 tables in each column, but they're not aligned.

```
ods html file="test.html";
ods layout gridded 
        columns=2;

ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;

ods region;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables age;
run;

ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.cars;
run;

ods region;
proc freq data=sashelp.cars;
tables origin;
run;

ods layout end;
ods html close;
```

This has a proper grid layout.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. we are almost there with this. i have added four proc report statements, with the expectation that i would get two pages, each with two reports on, however only the first two were included. is there a bit that needs adding?

Comment: there is no requirement that they are on multiple pages btw, that is just how my initial coding did it. as long as i have a stack of 2x2 tables that i can read into excel, that is fine...

Comment: Well, HTML doesn't have "pages" per se.  Are you still talking HTML?

Comment: yes. the page break bit is not important just the 2x2, 2x2, 2x2 stacked format

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in the end by tweaking the above as so:

```
ods layout gridded columns=2 rows=2;

ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;

ods region;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables age;
run;

ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.cars;
run;

ods region;
proc freq data=sashelp.cars;
tables origin;
run;

ods layout end;
```

Obviously, rows and columns will change depending on your needs. This produces a SAS report, that I then exported as a step in the project as a HTML file.

Thanks